# Notepad++ ignoring search results on same line

Tags: notepad++

When you perform a search of a bunch of files in Notepad++, if it finds the text you were looking for in the same line multiple times, the search results window will display the same line multiple times, with each different instance highlighted.

Is there a way to toggle that functionality? Sometimes it is nice to have, but other times i would like it turned off.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer the question there is not that functionality, but it would be a good idea. Feature requests for Notepad++ can be submitted through [IdeaTorrent](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/most_popular_ever/).

A work around is to use a regular expression that swallows the rest of the line. For example is you want to find lines containing abc you can search for '.*abc.*' under regular expressions and that will find every line with abc but will only list it once.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew mentioned, the best workaround I could find was RegEx.
I wanted the specific text to still be highlighted in the search results, and Notepad++ RegEx doesn't support variable length lookbehind, so I ended up using a negative lookahead like this

```
ABC(?!.*ABC)
```

That way it only finds that last instance of ABC on any given line, but it still highlights ABC.